# How to allow user input for a data point in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I believe that I have a pretty amatuer question here, I've been wracking my brain over linked lists for the past few days (end goal is building a multilist), but right now I'm working with my "addNode" function and I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to input the data point rather than hard coding the point into the program. My addNode function looks as such:

```
void List::AddNode(int addData) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->classpointer = NULL;
    n->class_number = addData;

    cout << "What value would you like to add?" << endl;

    //I believe that right here is where I need to figure out 
    //how to allow the user to add what they want the data point to be.

    if(head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->classpointer != NULL) {
            curr = curr->classpointer;
        }
        curr->classpointer = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

All in all I'm looking for some guidance on how to allow the user to input this data point. If you need to see more of the code that I have please just let me know, thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the standard input for something like this. Just like you used "cout" to send data out to the console, you use "cin" to read data in from the console. Like so:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

The program will wait here until you enter something.

And a note on your method, if you use a tail pointer to keep track of end of the linked list, you can do constant time addNode as opposed to O(N) as you are doing now. This means adding a private member, "tail", to your class.

Comment: I'm kind of taking it one step at a time. The end goal is creating a multi linked list, but I'm just starting out with a singly linked list and making sure I can get it all working correctly. But what do you mean by "constant time" addNode?

Comment: Also, In my main() function, I was calling List.addNode("insert int value here") to input the data, but when I want the user to input the data, how do I call that function without inputting an int value when I call for it?

Comment: If familiar with big-O notation, constant time is O(1). Right now, you iterate through the entire linked list, all N nodes, meaning the computer has to process N nodes to get to the end. If you had a tail pointer, you don't waste that processing time and it only takes one extra pointer. Now you can instantly place a new node at the end of the list. If your list was VERY long, it would have taken the computer some time to have found the end if you iterate through like you do now.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I remember that now. Any idea how to answer my second comment?

Comment: And you can do really two things. 1) Insert the two lines from my answer after you asked "What value would you like to add?", then immediately set the node data to x. This means you can remove that parameter all together since there's no use for it. 2) Add those two lines inside your main function and then pass in x to addNode.